# Tensorflow 0.8 Import and Export output tensors problems

Tags: import, export, neural-network, tensorflow, python-3.5

I am using Tensorflow 0.8 with Python 3. I am trying to train the Neural Network, and the goal is to automatically export/import network states every 50 iteration. The problem is when I export the output tensor at the first iteration, the output tensor name is `['Neg:0', 'Slice:0']`, but when I export the output tensor at the second iteration, the output tensor name is changed as `['import/Neg:0', 'import/Slice:0']`, and importing this output tensor is not working then:

```
ValueError: Specified colocation to an op that does not exist during import: import/Variable in import/Variable/read
```

I wonder if anyone has ideas on this problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: For clarification, does your graph structure change between iterations, or do you just want to import a different set of weights?

Comment: @mrry Actually, I just want to export/import different set of weights without changing the graph structure :) I think there might be a bug here for import/export in Tensorflow 0.8. (and I'm pretty sure my code has no problems, as it works very well for Tensorflow 0.6)

Comment: It does sound like a bug in the importer - are you passing variables to the `input_map` in `tf.import_graph_def()`? However, I think your main problem could be solved by simply using `tf.train.Saver` to save and restore from different checkpoints.

Comment: @mrry Well, I definitely used `saver` in my code. I think the problem here is the variable naming problem, which should be broken in 0.8. And 0.8 cannot find the variable name in the internal built dictionary.

Comment: I'm still unclear about how you're using `tf.import_graph_def()`. It might be time to move this to a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

Answer (score 2):

That's how `tf.import_graph_def` works.

If you don't want the prefix, just set the `name` parameter to the empty string as showed in the following example.

```
# import the model into the current graph
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:

    const_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with open(TRAINED_MODEL_FILENAME, 'rb') as saved_graph:
      const_graph_def.ParseFromString(saved_graph.read())
      # replace current graph with the saved graph def (and content)
      # name="" is important because otherwise (with name=None)
      # the graph definitions will be prefixed with import.
      # eg: the defined operation FC2/unscaled_logits:0
      # will be import/FC2/unscaled_logits:0
      tf.import_graph_def(const_graph_def, name="")
    [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Basically, I used the same import function as you showed here. And my goal is to automatically export/import network states every 50 iteration during the train. As I mentioned in my question, for the first time of `export` and `import`, it works well, but for the second time for importing network, it hit the problem: Some of the ops are not found... For example, `ValueError: Specified colocation to an op that does not exist during import: Variable_10 in Variable/read_1`. I tried the exact same code using tf 0.6, and everything works very well. I guess it's broken in 0.8

Comment: raise ValueError('tf.import_graph_def() requires a non-empty `name` '                             
ValueError: tf.import_graph_def() requires a non-empty `name` if `input_map` is used.