# Tensorflow 0.6 GPU Issue

Tags: gpu, tensorflow, nvidia-digits

I am using Nvidia Digits Box with GPU (Nvidia GeForce GTX Titan X) and Tensorflow 0.6 to train the Neural Network, and everything works. However, when I check the `Volatile GPU Util` using `nvidia-smi -l 1`, I notice that it's only 6%, and I think most of the computation is on CPU, since I notice that the process which runs Tensorflow has about 90% CPU usage. The result is the training process is very slow. I wonder if there are ways to make full usage of GPU instead of CPU to speed up the training process. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you have a bottleneck somewhere (like in this github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/838))  -- you have some operation which doesn't have GPU implementation, so it's placed on CPU, and the GPU is idling because of data transfers. For instance, until recently `reduce_mean` was not implemented on GPU, and before that `Rank` was not implemented on GPU, and it was implicitly being used by many ops.

At one point, I saw a network from [fully_connected_preloaded.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_preloaded.py) being slow because there was a `Rank` op that got placed on CPU, and hence triggering the transfer of entire dataset from GPU to CPU at each step.

To solve this I would first recommend upgrading to 0.8 since it had a few more ops implemented for GPU (`reduce_prod` for integer inputs, `reduce_mean` and others).

Then you can create your session with `log_device_placement=True` and see if there are any ops placed on CPU or GPU that would cause excessive transfers per step.

There are often ops in the input pipeline (such as `parse_example`) which don't have GPU implementations, I find it helpful sometimes to pin the whole input pipeline to CPU using `with tf.device("/cpu:0"):` block

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! After I did some profiling work, I noticed that `tensor.eval(session=..., feed_dict=...)` takes too much time, and the time consumption grows as code running time goes by. I wonder how I can improve this function usage, and I really appreciate it :) (BTW, I am using Tensorflow 0.6, I tried to upgrade it to 0.8, but I got the problems there - I guess that may be Tensorflow 0.8 bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877559/tensorflow-0-8-import-and-export-output-tensors-problems. I also wonder if I can improve `tensor.eval()` usage if I still keep using 0.6)